# symfony 2.4.4 trying to force a pdo_mysql connection instead of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.4

i'm pretty new Symfony2. I installed FOSUserBundle and DoctrineMongoDBBundle and i'm trying to make these works correctly together. 
In my previous project, I managed to create a new user and import user list, from my mongoDB database. this previous project was with symfony version 2.1.x-dev, according to my composer.json.
On my new project, i'm using symfony ~2.4. And i can't  manage to load the /register page on FOSUserBundle. Instead of loading the registration form, symfony throw this error :

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

So Symfony is trying to use a pdo_mysql driver instead of connecting to the mongoDB, as it was doing perfectly in my previous project. I followed the same steps, according to the FOSUserBundle documentation : in app/config/config.yml, i set doctrine_mongodb and fos_user information like this :

```
#doctrine_mongodb
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: agitw
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true

#fos user
fos_user:
    db_driver:     mongodb
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:    Van\UserBundle\Document\User
```

I'm pretty sure this behavior is caused by symfony 2.4, as i can't reproduce it with my symfony 2.1 project.
Does anyone knows why symfony is trying to force a pdo_mysql connection despite I filled correctly the config file ?

Comment: What do you have in security.yml?

Comment: this : http://jsfiddle.net/3gt4D/ are u seeing any mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, after a lot of digging.
If you are using Symfony with MongoDB, you need to comment all the "doctrine:" part in the app/config/config.yml file. My file was filled with that "doctrine:" part and the "doctrine_mongodb:" part. And it seems if "doctrine:" config is set, symfony will use it before any other DB.